# Read data from sql-server and update the table after performing some calculation in microsoft visual foxpro

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I am trying to solve a problem in Visual FoxPro where I have to read the data from SQL server database tables and update the tables in the SQL-server after performing some calculation.

Comment: Please include an example describing the problem you want to solve

Comment: That's quite possible. The VFP functions you'll need to use are SQLConnect(), SQLExec() and SQLDisconnect(). Do you have specific questions about how to use them?